# Limit at infinity for sequence $x^{1/(2n-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{1/(2n-1)}=    \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
      0, & \text{if}\ x=0\\
      -1, & \text{if}\ x<0
    \end{cases}$.

But I have no idea where to start. I don't know how a definition of the limit could be applied here, if at all. Could the Monotone Convergence Theorem be applied here? Totally lost, would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x=0$ the terms are identically $0$, so there is nothing to prove.

For $x>0$, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{\frac1{2n-1}} &= e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} \log\left(x^{\frac1{2n-1}}\right)}\\
&= e^{\log x\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n+1} }\\
&= e^0\\
&=1.
\end{align}
For $x<0$, let $y=-x$, then $y>0$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{\frac1{2n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{\frac1{2n-1}}\lim_{n\to\infty}y^{\frac1{2n-1}}=-1\cdot1, $$
if we take the real root when evaluating $(-1)^{\frac1{2n-1}}$.

Comment: Why $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{\frac1{2n-1}} = -1$? How can we guarantee that we're only taking the real root of it?

Comment: See @Barry Cipra's comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wrong problem. Because the function $x^\alpha$ ($\alpha \in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Z$) is not well-defined if $x<0$.

Comment: The variable $n$ is usually understood to be an integer, in which case the exponent $1/(2n-1)$ is an odd root, which *is* well defined for $x\lt0$.